# PHP: How to Execute the Multiple Query using mysql_multi_query()

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I am working on two SQL which are similar just difference is in first query stock is calculated between two dates and second query using current date.

PHP:

```
   $sql="select all_dates.value1 as `Date`, sum(coalesce(`Inward(B_Qty)`, '0')) as `Inward`, sum(coalesce(`Outward(B_Qty)`, '0')) as `Outward` 
    from ( select distinct M_Date as value1 from machine where J_Name = '180MLGMV' and DATE(M_Date) between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-06' 
    union select distinct M_Date from machine where Pre_Req = '180MLGMV' and DATE(M_Date) between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-06' ) as all_dates 
    left join (select M_Date, sum(A_Prod) AS `Inward(B_Qty)` 
    from machine where J_Name = '180MLGMV' and DATE(M_Date) between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-06' group by M_Date) 
    as g on g.M_Date = all_dates.value1 
    left join( select M_Date, sum(NoBot) AS `Outward(B_Qty)` 
    from machine where Pre_req ='180MLGMV' and DATE(M_Date) between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-06' group by M_Date) 
    as f on f.M_Date = all_dates.value1 group by all_dates.value1 ;" ;

    $sql.="select all_dates.value1 as `Date`, sum(coalesce(`Inward(B_Qty)`, '0')) as `Inward`, sum(coalesce(`Outward(B_Qty)`, '0')) as `Outward` 
    from ( select distinct M_Date as value1 from machine where J_Name = '180MLGMV' and M_Date='2016-06-07'
    union select distinct M_Date from machine where Pre_Req = '180MLGMV' and M_Date='2016-06-07' ) as all_dates 
    left join (select M_Date, sum(A_Prod) AS `Inward(B_Qty)` 
    from machine where J_Name = '180MLGMV' and M_Date='2016-06-07' group by M_Date) 
    as g on g.M_Date = all_dates.value1 
    left join( select M_Date, sum(NoBot) AS `Outward(B_Qty)` 
    from machine where Pre_req ='180MLGMV' and M_Date='2016-06-07' group by M_Date) 
    as f on f.M_Date = all_dates.value1 group by all_dates.value1 "; 

    $list1=mysqli_multi_query($sql,$con);
    while($row_list1=mysql_fetch_array($list1))
               { 
                 $b=$b+$row_list1['Inward'];
                $c=$c+$row_list1['Outward'];


}
```

Please suggest how to retrieve the data of Date,Inward and outward of each Query.I mean what should write below the mysqli_multi_query to retrieve the four data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please go through http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp. Have clear Idea, First.

Comment: @RyanVincent Actually I had already tried the Query there are working absolutely fine.I just got confusion regarding to retrieve the values.

Comment: @NanaPartykar Yeah.I am going through that Only..Thanks.

Comment: Hey @RyanVincent, Why To Say Sorry Man. You Gave Your Suggestion. Which Are Always Welcome In SO.

Answer (score 0):

This example from the manual on [`mysql_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) explains how to get multiple values using the `multi_query` function.

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        /* print divider */
        if (mysqli_more_results($link)) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
}
```

Comment: Okay.I will go through that.Thanks.